# how to add each values inside <li> element with next <li> element?

Tags: jquery

I have `ul` element with values in each `li` elements.I want to add each `li` value to next `li` element value and display the sum.

```
<ul class=`sum`>
<li>7</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>9</li>
</ul>
```

how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  I suggest trying to use the jquery method `closest`

Answer (score 1):

You can add them all up by getting the innerHTML of each child of the `<ul>` element. jQuery provides children() to get the children of a root node.

```js
function getSum() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.sum').children().each(function(index, value) {
    total += parseInt(value.innerHTML.trim(), 10);
  });
  return total;
}

var total = getSum();
console.log(total);
alert("The total is " + total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sum">
<li>7</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: from where to call the function getSum() ?

Comment: I would think that pretty much anywhere should work.

Comment: You can use the return value of getSum and do whatever with it

Comment: this is not working for me..it is displaying only the first li value..not summing all the values

Comment: how come this answer wasn't working for u @annasujith

Comment: ss..its only displaying the value of the first li element now

Answer (score 0):

```js
var li = $('.sum li').map(function() {


  return $(this).text()
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
}, 0);

console.log(li)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class=sum>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Use this way

Comment: parse them to make it int or float. check the demo

Comment: I have used the same code as above using parseint..but it is not working..

Comment: can you create your problem in snippet?

Comment: i have created the snippet abov..pls check.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var li = $('.sum li').map(function() {


  return $(this).text()
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
}, 0);

console.log(li);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sum">
  <li>7</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is my code it is not working when i am pasting into a separate file..its showing the total as 0

Comment: when i am typing this code in local server, its showing zero as total.

Comment: this should not even be here this is already given as answer. this does not change the fact that your problem maybe cause by other factor not given in the OP\